# Show that a dot product is defined on a certain vector space $P_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

Let $P_2 = \{p:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R} \mid p(x) = ax^2+bx+c,$ with $ a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}\}$ be a vector space of polynomials up to second degree.

And the dot product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle:P_2\times P_2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as:
$$\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle = \int_{-1}^1p(x)q(x)\,dx$$

How do I show that the dot product is defined on $P_2$?

I've tried to solve the integral as such:
$$
\int_{-1}^1p(x)q(x)\,dx =
\int_{-1}^1(ax^2+bx+c)(\tilde{a}x^2+\tilde{b}x+\tilde{c})\,dx =
\cdots =
2a\left(\frac{\tilde{a}}{5}+\frac{\tilde{c}}{3}\right)+2c\tilde{c}
$$
Since $\tilde{a}, c, \tilde{c} \in \mathbb{R}$ and the last bit
$$2a\left(\frac{\tilde{a}}{5}+\frac{\tilde{c}}{3}\right)+2c\tilde{c}$$
can attain all values in $\mathbb{R}$ (which is the same for $P_2$), have I then showed what's needed?

Comment: Being defined is the least of your concerns. What you have to show is that it's symmetric, bilinear, and positive-definite.

Comment: Where is the meaning in defining something and asking if it is defined? You can define what ever you want. If you want to use the properties of a dot product, I suggest you verify that your definition is equivalent to the 'usual' definition of the dot product. I.e. do what Arnaut said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to calculate it explicitly.

$$\langle p,p\rangle = \int_{-1}^1 p(x)^2 \,dx  \ge 0$$ and $\langle p,p\rangle = 0$ if and only if $p(x) = 0$ for all $[-1,1]$ which is equivalent to $p = 0$ (because a nonzero polynomial cannot have an infinite number of zeros).

Linearity directly follows from the linearity of the intergral:

$$\langle \alpha p + \beta q, r\rangle = \int_{-1}^1 (\alpha p + \beta q)(x) r(x) \,dx = \int_{-1}^1 (\alpha p(x) + \beta q(x)) r(x) \,dx \\= \alpha \int_{-1}^1 p(x)r(x)\,dx + \beta \int_{-1}^1 q(x)r(x)\,dx = \alpha \langle p, r\rangle + \beta \langle q, r\rangle$$

Symmetry is obvious:

$$\langle p, q\rangle = \int_{-1}^1 p(x)q(x)\,dx = \int_{-1}^1 q(x)p(x)\,dx = \langle q,p\rangle$$

And there you have it.

Comment: Thanks! So positive definite, linear and symmetric are the three conditions that always needs to be true for a defined dot product?

Comment: @Void Yes, an inner product on a vector space $V$ over a field $\mathbb{F}$ is a function $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle : V \times V \to \mathbb{F}$ which is positive definite, linear and symmetric. Note that if $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{C}$ then symmetry is defined as $\langle x,y\rangle = \overline{\langle y,x\rangle}$.

Comment: Also if $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{C}$ then an inner product is no longer bilinear, only *sesquilinear* (i.e. depending on the exact definition you use, possibly $\langle \alpha x, y \rangle = \bar \alpha \langle x, y \rangle$ and $\langle x, \alpha y \rangle = \alpha \langle x, y \rangle$.)